# Eclipse workspace error: Source not found

Tags: java, eclipse

I stored all my projects in the workspace "JAVA CODE" but once the project did not launch and I decided to save everything in another work space "java for assignments". I wrote the entire project in the new work space "java for assignments" (I think I did). However, when I started debugging my codes I got the msg: Source not found. Edit Source look up path.

Hence, I checked where the project was stored and I found that (very strangely) even though I was always opening and working in the new work space "java for assignments" Eclipse had stored everything in the old workspace  "JAVA CODE".But when I open Eclipse with work space "JAVA CODE" I dont see any project.

In short, the workspace in which i am working does not store the projects and the workspace that is storing the project does not show them when I open it in eclipse.

I have been trying to figure out a solution since few hours but no luck. I will appreciate any help.

Many thanks..!!!

Answer (score 0):

Look in your workspace and pull up your `.project` file in a text editor.  There you will find paths to your source code.  Chances are the paths are pointing outside of your workspace directory.  You can edit these paths if you like and move the source to the place where you want to keep it.

Your workspace directory contains your eclipse working files (like compiled class files and project information) in another directory.  You can also keep your source code there, but Eclipse doesn't demand this.  This allows you to  work with existing source in a different place without littering it with meta-information compiled output, which some people prefer.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
 <name>Userled</name>
 <comment></comment>
 <projects>
 </projects>
 <buildSpec>
  <buildCommand>
   <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
   <arguments>
   </arguments>
  </buildCommand>
 </buildSpec>
 <natures>
  <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
 </natures>
</projectDescription>
 My .project files looks like above but i cant figure out what to do with it.

Comment: Ugh, there may be another variable in another hidden file, or dig around in the eclipse preferences.  I wish I could be of more help here.  If you can't totally understand the problem, create a new workspace and then copy the code into it to get back to sanity!